# cPanel index.php permission error

Tags: php, zip, ubuntu-12.04, cpanel, file-permissions

i have get problem when,I am extract zip file in c panel made from Ubuntu OS,it give permission 664 to index.php so it gives 500 internal server error,actually it should be 644,
the same thing I am doing with the zip made from windows OS works perfectly means index.php has given 644 permission by default.
any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip doesn't support saving file ownership/permission. Can you please try to create tar file on your Ubuntu OS and try to extract it on your cPanel account.